# What do you say to check-in or passport control when going on fieldwork/research leave?

Tags: research-process, travel

I am going on fieldwork to UAE in a couple of  days' time. I'm researching parts of the local music scene in Abu Dhabi/Dubai. What is the right thing to say to check-in/passport control? Does one say one is going on research leave? Fieldwork? Or is it just simpler to say it's a holiday?

I take it one does not say "business" since no money is being earned. I ask because I think saying "fieldwork" could lead to question after question, but I just want to do the right thing.

EDIT: **I would advise anyone reading this question to look at my answer at the bottom** [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195045/68021) which shows what actually happened when I came to the airport. In the end I did not say "holiday" or "business" but "academic research for music".

Comment: The nature of "fieldwork" seems very field-dependent, what sort of work are you doing?

Comment: @BryanKrause Maybe I should have been more specific, it's research in music. It's not scientific, it's arts-based. Basically researching the local music scene.

Comment: I see. I'm not near enough to your field to know how that would be treated and whether there's need for ethical approvals, etc. Some countries are really touchy on these things due to a history of colonialism, etc.

Comment: Do not under any circumstance say something that is not true, even if it seems “simpler”. In most countries, immigration officials will not take kindly to being lied to. I could easily see this as leading to denial of entry, deportation, and possibly even arrest.

Comment: @DanRomik "researching ... *the local music scene*" sure sounds like holiday to me...

Comment: Make sure you don't ''white lie'', these officials usually have a certain amount of power and can probably refuse you entry if they don't like something you say.

Comment: @RonJohn And there is [musicology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musicology). Perhaps not on academic level, The Beatles did so [in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles_in_India), [Menuhin](https://www.thenewsminute.com/article/yehudi-menuhins-desi-connect-five-indians-who-influenced-his-life-and-music-51807). You don't have to divide an octave in 12 intervals, [microtonal music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtonal_music) is at least as popular than contemporary western 12TET / equal temperament in Iran and India (e.g., [shruti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shruti_(music)).

Comment: @Buttonwood yes, this is for my PhD in music, which draws a lot from ethnomusicology.

Comment: @Buttonwood in highly urban Dubai, is "the local music scene" going out into the desert and listening to old men, or is it going to clubs and listening to Mustafa Ismail?

Comment: @RonJohn Again, this isn't my field, but in other fields it completely changes the interaction when any sort of research aspect is involved. For example, anyone can observe a classroom without special permission from anyone but the teacher, but if you want to observe a classroom *for research* you'd be expected to go through IRB. You don't need special permission to talk to people at a bar where music is being played, but if you plan to use those conversations *for research* you need IRB approval. Multiple approvals may be necessary when working across country borders.

Comment: "I take it one does not say "business" since no money is being earned." Regardless of the specifics of your situation, this is actually incorrect. In this context, the term "business" is as opposed to "pleasure", and the distinction is whether you are going because you felt like it, or because it's part of some encompassing activity, be it research, trade, technical work, or whatever. The actual exchange of money has no bearing on the question.

Comment: Not a single mention of "learning" or "studying" in any answer or comment on this page, yet that is exactly what you are doing and neither are going to be trigger words like "research" and "fieldwork".  "I've come to Dubai to learn more about the music here as part of my PhD studies"

Comment: @StingyJack: That sounds like a complete answer.

Comment: In certain countries 'research', particularly undeclared research, can be taken as 'spying'. Which is a ticket to some very hot water, particularly if you happen to be doing it in a way that strays into some sensitive territory (politics, strategic locations, etc). Being upfront about it is more likely to get a denied visa but less likely to get arrested. You may end up on their radar though, so you would best be aware of sensitivities in any case.

Comment: It is rather naïve to think its not business if money isn't earned. Is the trip entirely personally funded? Or is a 3rd party paying for anything? Are you being reimbursed for any expenses? Is there any 3rd party that is interested in the results of this research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question myself to give feedback on how things transpired. There have been a lot of helpful comments, though there has also been some speculation and I think it's important that the record is set straight. I would like to thank benwiggy for his answer since it was the most helpful to me, though I still think it is better that I answer the question since I can report on what actually happened.

In the end I was not asked in the UAE at all what the purpose of my trip was. I was, however, asked in the UK outbound from Gatwick. First of all when I got to the Qatar Airways check-in desk the girl asked me if I needed a visa, which I thought was a nice question since a lot of airlines will just assume you have one sorted out. Now, as a UK resident, one does not need a visa if one is staying in the UAE under 30 days [and not earning]. I told her that I was doing academic research in music. She asked how long for, I said about 3 weeks, and she just said that was fine and took my bags.

At the gate when about to board the plane I was stopped by someone who identified themselves as a plain-clothes policeman asking me what the purpose of my trip was. He said, "you don't get many single guys travelling on Qatar, it's normally families or couples". I told him I was doing academic research - and that it was music-related. He asked me what genre and I told him it was hard rock/metal mixed with Middle Eastern influences - "that's quite a fusion" was his comment. He let me go after tapping a few things on his phone.

I transited at Doha and nobody asked me anything. When I got to passport control in Abu Dhabi the only thing I was asked was, "is this your first time here?" and that was it.

Now, of course the info at Gatwick could have been passed 'down the line' but it also could not have been. The reason I say this is because if there is one thing I have found in the few days that I have been here is that everyone is incredibly welcoming and friendly. Everybody speaks English [that I have met] and everyone is very respectful; I should also mention the architecture which is nothing short of breathtaking. The UAE is clearly successfully modernising while retaining its traditional core values and seems to want to welcome as many people here as it can. It has been a great stay so far and I would recommend others come here to see for themselves if they have the opportunity.

Answer (score 32):

You will need to check in which category fieldwork falls for the UAE - and in particular, whether it is even covered by the visa-free/visa-on-arrival scheme there or not. It would not surprise me at all if you would need particular permissions/paperwork to conduct fieldwork. For example, the UK has a particular "research" purpose for the standard visa/visa-free route, which has some rather peculiar requirements.

Claiming to be there for a holiday is a clear lie, and could get you into significant trouble.

"Business" is the correct answer for most trips we do as academics (e.g. attending conferences, meeting with collaborators).

It is generally ill advised to ever use the word "work" when talking to immigration-related people if you do not have a work visa.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose it depends what question they ask you, but "I'm doing some academic research" seems both simple and truthful. If they have follow-up questions, they'll ask them.

Broadly, they aren't interested in what you're doing; just whether your answers and your paperwork matches.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what you call it. Either it's allowed or it's not allowed, no matter what you want to call it. It sounds like either you're not sure or you think it probably isn't and don't want to confirm that. This is a huge problem. (I'll note that the question you asked is *not* "Am I allowed to go on fieldwork research?" but "What do I tell them so they'll let me in?")

Your first priority needs to be finding out whether or not what you want to do is actually allowed visa-free. If not, your next priority needs to be finding out which visa you need to get and how to get it. Trying to trick or mislead a passport agent into letting you in on the wrong status is a very dangerous game with significant potential consequences.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should tell the truth and the real reason you go where you go. There is nothing worse than a lie to a passport security I reckon. Maybe it would be possible to get some letter or a paper with a signature of your supervisor and a dean. That would help be more transparent at the gate.